# Access real time Heart Rate data on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit

Can we access the heart rate directly from the apple watch? I know this is a duplicate question, but no one has asked this in like 5 years. I know you can access it from the Health App but I'm not sure how "real-time" that will be.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't expect 100% real-time.

You can use this one: [HKAnchoredObjectQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkanchoredobjectquery/executing_anchored_object_queries). I think it has a 300-500ms delay.

> A query that returns changes to the HealthKit store, including a snapshot of new changes and continuous monitoring as a long-running query.