# How do I get live Heart Rate data from the iPhone health app using swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, healthkit

My current heart rate function to get the heart rate data works, however it only retrieves the first data it gets, meaning it does not get any more data after initialisation, and repeatedly calling the function still gives the same heart rate, even though I can see on my watch that the heart rate BPM has changed.
Here is my function:

```
    func readHeartRate() async throws -> Double {
        let heartRateType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRateType, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
                if let heartRate = results?.first as? HKQuantitySample {
                    let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
                    let beatsPerMinute = heartRate.quantity.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
                    continuation.resume(returning: beatsPerMinute)
                } else {
                    let unknownError = NSError(domain: "com.ray.app", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unknown error occurred"])
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error ?? unknownError)
                }
            }
            store.execute(query)
        }
    }
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Looking at the method signature, possibly something to do with limiting the returned query results to 1 data set and then always taking the first item returned?

Comment: @flanker but thats to get the latest item in the data set.

Comment: @Game_Time, here is my related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74042669/17286292

Comment: @Neklas I have already tried that, it still was not working for me. Could you show me a code snippet of sort from your code if you can please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current logic, using [HKAnchoredObjectQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkanchoredobjectquery)

```
    // At the beginning of file
    let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
    
    // In your function
    // Start from [Now]
    let startDate = Date()
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: nil, options: HKQueryOptions())
    
    let queryHeartRate = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
    }
    
    queryHeartRate.updateHandler = { [weak self](query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        guard let _self = self else { return }
        if let heartRateSample = samples?.last as? HKQuantitySample {
            
            let unit = HKUnit.heartRate()
            let heartRateValue = Int(heartRateSample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit))
            print("Current HR: \(heartRateValue)")
        }
    }
    
    self.healthKitStore.execute(queryHeartRate)
```